# Set password reset limit for periodic time for firebase auth user

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, change-password

I want to create a mechanism for a password reset using Node JS and firebase. The user's profile is stored in firebase auth.

**My aim:** from the GUI, a user request for a password reset email. A user can request for reset password a maximum of 3 times within 1 hour. If still, he doesn't get reset email then he can request again after 1 hour.

I thought about several options to do this, but not sure which one is better for good performance and security. From my point of view, I need to store two values: request number and request time. I thought about below ways to do this:

1. Create a document in the firestore to maintain these two values.
2. Use customClaims of the firebase auth user to maintain these two values.
3. Use client-side cookies to request numbers and use customClaims to store request time.

I thought using the 1st and 2nd option will lead to several firebase operations. Which end up charging me unnecessarily more cost for read/write operations. And the 3rd option will create a loophole.

Can you suggest a better option or which option should I choose from the above for implementing the reset password mechanism which avoids multiple requests from the same user for a periodic time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing the number of password resets in firebase database or even keep a history of that. When user requests to change password, check his last reset and `if-else` statement will do rest of the job.

For example let's say I'm an user of your app and reset the password now, then you store current time in your database and update number of resets in last 1 hour.
You will have to fetch this information when I am about to change password again.
So when I click password reset button, fetch this information.

Store the time in the form of timestamp. Means timestamp now is around `1588570404`. Get the timestamp at the moment when reset button is pressed and use `if-else`.

```
if(timeDifference <= 3600) {
//deny resetting as time since last reset is less than an hour
}
else {
//reset password
}
```

1 hour comprises of 3600 seconds so the difference should be greater than 3600 seconds.
You can add additional conditions to check how many times the user has changed password within last hour as mentioned above the code.

But you will need to reset that count after every hours so good luck with that. Maybe your can reset it when you perform checks for last reset.